# HTML and ASP codes arent working

Tags: html, asp-classic, null

I have two separate files, one HTML, the other ASP. Ive looked at numerous guides, and i still cant fix it. When I save these files and test them out, the message is always "null".Why doesnt this work?

First file, html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form name="formName" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Enter">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Second, asp file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script>
    var x=document.getElementById("name");
    alert(x);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the first page posts to the second, `document.getElementById("name");` will never work, since the input doesn't exist on that page - you're trying to access something that is a query-string value.

This answer to a related question seems to be the most solid method of getting query string parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929/534109

Using that code, you replace what you're doing on the second page with:

```
alert(urlParams["name"]);
```

You would of course have to include the referenced code first.

Answer (score 0):

To do it Classic ASP way, first give the input box a name: (can be same as the id)

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
```

Now its value will be sent when you click the submit button.

Next step is having such code in *html_form_action.asp*:

```javascript
var x = '<%=Replace(Request("name"), "'", "\'")%>';
alert(x);
```

This will now show alert with whatever you typed in the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a form in html, you should use a `name=""`...
Your html code for the html file should be:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="formName" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
<input type="text" id="name" name="TheNameOfTheInput">
<input type="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have an asp file, you should use asp... replace this:

```
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("name");
alert(x);
</script>
```

with(without `<script>` and `</script>`):

```
<%
response.write(request.querystring("TheNameOfTheInput"))
%>
```

Tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_inputforms.asp :)

Answer (score -1):

Never touched asp but according to your code I think there are three problems.

- The method of the form should be POST.
- Give the input another id instead of 'name'
- Give the input an 'name' attribute e.g.

  `<input name="name" id="somethingElse">`